# Displaying an array of integers does not work

Tags: java, arrays, integer, int, double

I have the following piece of code used to calculate Heart Rate from an ECG Signal by detecting the QRS peaks:

```
public class Heart_Rate {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // Read Text file
    Path filePath = Paths.get("heartrate.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filePath);
    List<Double> rawData = new ArrayList<Double>();

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            rawData.add(scanner.nextDouble());
        } else {
            scanner.next();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(rawData);

    //Find Max value for Threshold Level
    Double maximum = Collections.max(rawData);
    Double threshold = 0.7*maximum;

    System.out.println("Maximum = " + maximum);
    System.out.println("Threshold = " + threshold);

    //Calculate Heart Rate from list "Raw Data"
    int upflag = 0;
    int last = 1;
    int p = 0;
    int t = 0;
    int count = 0;
    //List<Double> heartRate = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int heartRate2[] = new int[50];

    for (int i = 0; i < rawData.size(); i++) {
        if (rawData.get(i)> threshold){
            if (upflag == 0){
                if (last > 0){
                    t = i - last;
                    p = 100*60/t;
                    //100 is the sampling rate
                    heartRate2[count] = p;
                    count = count + 1;
                    //heartRate.add(p);

                }
                last = i;
            }
            upflag = 50;
        }
        else {
            if (upflag > 0){
                upflag = upflag -1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Count = " + count);
    System.out.println("Heart Rate = " + heartRate2);
    System.out.println("Heart Rate = " + heartRate2);

    }


}
```

When I add the heart rate values calculated(p) to my ArrayList (called HeartRate), I received a proper array of values.
However, I tried to change all my values to int and save my values in an integer array (called heartRate2) I get the following result:
Heart Rate = [I@dd1e765
I need my values to be integers since heart rate is calculated in beats per minute. I also tried converting the double values to int but ended up receiving a similar result as above.

Comment: "[I@dd1e765" *is* an array of integers.  The `[` indicates "array", the "I" indicates "integer", and the "dd1e765" is the hash value assigned to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.toString(arr)` to get a meaningful `String` representation for some array `arr`.